# list of boost::spirit skip parsers

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I am looking for a skip parser that skips all whitespace characters: spaces, tabs, carriage returns.  does ascii::space_type do this?

I poked around the documentation and the web for some time, but was unable to find a list of skip parsers and what they do.  Can someone  provide one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the character class parsers:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html

`space_type` indeed does effectively what you described (unless you meant "carriage returns" literally, in which case `blank | lit('\r')` would be closer)